# Inner measure of Vitali Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $V$ be the Vitali set. Show that if $E$ is measurable and $E \subset V$, then $|E|=0$. Prove that $|V|_i=0$.

I don't know what to do in the first part. As for the second part, $|V|_i=\sup\{ |F|: F \subset V, F \space \text{closed}\}.$ Since closed sets are measurable, we have $|F|=0$ for all closed sets contained in $V$. From here it follows that the inner measure is $0$. Any suggestions for the other statement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the properties of $V$ coming from its construction.

The two properties we need to use are:

1. Translations of $V$ by a rational number are disjoint.
2. the union of all translations of $V$ by rational numbers in $[0,1]$ is contained in a finite interval, say $[-1,2]$ to use the same in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

If $E\subset V$ is measurable then $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(E+r)\subset\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(V+r)\subset [-1,2]$.

Therefore $|\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(E+r)|=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}|E+r|=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}|E|\leq(2-(-1))=3$

Therefore $|E|=0$.