# Does monotonicity apply to non-measurable sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show that if $\mathcal{N}$ is a non-measurable set (namely, the Vitali set), and $E \subseteq \mathcal{N}$ then $m(E) = 0$. My first approach was to use contradiction and assume that $m(E) \gt 0$, then apply monotonicity and say that $ E \subseteq \mathcal{N} \Rightarrow m(E) \le m(\mathcal{N}) \Rightarrow 0 < m(\mathcal{N}) $, which leads to a contradiction because $\mathcal{N}$ is not measurable. But I feel like this may be problematic because I'm not sure if monotonicity holds when one of the sets is not measurable. Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: It is paradoxical to say "the measure of a nonmeasurable set" :).

Comment: Lebesgue measure is certainly monotone, as you can check from the definition; measurability just has to do with whether a set is in a certain $\sigma$-algebra (where $m$ has nice properties on members of this $\sigma$-algebra), and doesn't preclude the formula from making sense.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think the hypothesis is true. For example, let $S$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $(0, 1)$, and consider $\mathcal{N} = S\cup (-1, 0)$. Then, $E = (-1, 0)\subset \mathcal{N}$, but $m(E) = 1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211067/inner-measure-of-vitali-set

Comment: Your hypothesis $E\subseteq\mathcal N$ permits $E=\mathcal N.$ Are you trying to show that, if $\mathcal N$ is non-measurable, then $m(\mathcal N)=0?$

Comment: Inner measure and outer measure are monotonic. If $E$ is a measurable subset of $\mathcal N,$ then the measure of $E$ is less than or equal to the inner measure of $\mathcal N.$

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed incorrect to use monotonicity the way you suggest.  If $A$ and $B$ are measurable and $A\subseteq B$, then $m(A)\leq m(B)$, but if (say) $B$ is not measurable, then $m(B)$ is not defined at all, and so it certainly isn't a theorem that $m(A)\leq m(B)$.

To solve your problem, I would suggest examining the proof that your set $\mathcal{N}$ is not measurable and see if you can use it to also say something about subsets of $\mathcal{N}$ which are measurable.