# Prob. 18, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: If $E$ has finite outer measure, then there is an $F_\sigma$-set $F$ and a $G_\delta$-set $G$ with ...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Here is Prob. 18, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Let $E$ have finite outer measure. Show that there is an $F_\sigma$ set $F$ and a $G_\delta$ set $G$ such that $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(F) = m^*(E) = m^*(G)$.

My Attempt:

> Case 1.  If set  $E$ is a (Lebesgue) measurable set of real numbers, then by Theorem 11 (iv), Chap. 2, in Royden, there is an $F_\sigma$ set $F$ with $F \subseteq E$ and $m^*(E \setminus F) = 0$, and by Theorem 11 (ii), there is a $G_\delta$ set $G$ such that $E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(G \setminus E) = 0$.

> Note that the sets $F$ and $G$ both are measurable.

> Now since $E$ is measurable with finite outer measure and since $F \subseteq E$, therefore $F$ also has finite outer measure.

> Thus we have $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$ and $m^*(E \setminus F) = 0$ and $m^*(G \setminus E) = 0$, which by the excision property of measurable sets (i.e. sets $F$ and $E$) with finite outer measure yield $m^*(E) - m^*(F) = 0$ and $m^*(G) - m^*(E) = 0$, and thus
> $$
> m^*(F) = m^*(E) = m^*(G),
> $$
> as required.

Is what I have done correct and accurate in each and every detail? If so, then how to tackle the case when $E$ has finite outer measure but is not measurable?

PS:

> Case 2. Now suppose that set $E$ has finite outer measure but is not measurable. Then by Theorem 11 (ii) and (iv) in Royden, for any $F_\sigma$ set $F$ and any $G_\delta$ set $G$ with $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$, we must have
> $m^*(E \setminus F) \neq 0$ and $m^*(G \setminus E) \neq 0$, that is, $m^*(E \setminus F) >  0$ and $m^*(G \setminus E) > 0$, which imply $E \setminus F \neq \emptyset$ and $G \setminus E \neq \emptyset$; in fact the sets $E \setminus F$ and $G \setminus E$ cannot even be countable.

> Now as $E = F \cup (E \setminus F)$, so we have
> $$
> m^*(E) = m^* \big( F \cup (E \setminus F) \big) \leq m^*(F) + m^*( E \setminus F),
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> m^*(E) - m^*(F) \leq m^*( E \setminus F),
> $$
> but since $F \subseteq E$, by the monotonicity of the outer measure we have
> $$
> 0 \leq m^*(E) - m^*(F) \leq m^*( E \setminus F). \tag{1} 
> $$

> And, as $G = E \cup (G \setminus E)$, so we have
> $$
> m^*(G) = m^* \big( E \cup (G \setminus E) \big) \leq m^*(E) + m^*( G \setminus E ), 
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> m^*(G) - m^*(E) \leq m^*(G \setminus E),
> $$
> but since $E \subset G$, by the monotonicity of the outer measure we have
> $$
> 0 \leq m^*(G) - m^*(E) \leq m^*(G \setminus E). \tag{2} 
> $$
> The relations (1) and (2) hold for any $F_\sigma$ set $F$ and for any $G_\delta$ set $G$ such that $F \subseteq E \subseteq G$.

What next? Where can we get from here?

PS (Based on the comments by Tab1e):

> As set $E$ has finite outer measure, so by the definition of the outer measure, for each positive integer $n$, we can find a countable collection $\left\{ I_{n, k} \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of non-empty bounded open intervals covering set $E$ for which
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{n, k} \right) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}, 
> $$
> Let us put
> $$
>  G_n := \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{n, k}.
> $$
> Then by our choice of the $I_{n, k}$, we have $E \subset G_n$, and also
> $$ m^*\left( G_n \right) = m^* \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{n, k} \right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m^* \left( I_{n, k} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{n, k} \right) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}, $$
> and hence we also have
> $$
> m^* \left( G_n \right) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n}.
> $$

> Let us now put
> $$
> G := \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n.
> $$
> This set $G$ is of course a $G_\delta$ set, and simce for each positive integer $n$ we have $G \subset G_n$ and $E \subset G_n$, we can conclude that $E \subset G$ also and therefore
> $$
> m^*(E) \leq m^* (G) \leq m^* \left( G_n \right) < m^*(E) + \frac{1}{n},
> $$
> which in turn implies that
> $$
> m^*(E) \leq m^*(G) < m^*(E) + \frac1n 
> $$
> for every positive integer $n$, which upon taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ yields
> $$
> m^*(E) = m^*(G). 
> $$

Is this part of my post correct? If so, then how to give the proof for the $F_\sigma$ set?

Comment: Your attempt with measurable set $E$ looks good to me. However, I don't think that the approach you were taking is correct. The problem is about general set with finite outer measure, so you need to try to prove the problem from this prospective, since it is really easy under measurable assumption.

Comment: I suggest you first prove the $G_{\delta}$ statement with what you have learned at and before the Chapter about Lebesgue Outer Measure, which should be definitely doable. After that, prove the $F_{\delta}$ statement as a complement to $G_{\delta}$.

Comment: Also, you are so tunnel vision on Theorem 11, but what is one of the most important things in Mathematical Analysis? You haven't state or even consider the definitions of $G_{\delta}$ and $F_{\delta}$.

Comment: @Tab1e can you please have a look at my post now after I have added a second PS? Can you please help me out with the remaining part of the proof?

Comment: As two excellent answers were posted below, I am afraid that I am not professional enough with measure theory to teach you. At least I hope that my comments can help you with your future mathematics study. You should take a look at those answers and see whether you can understand them.

Answer (score 4):

The way you find sets $F$ and $G$ in your posting under the assumption that $E$ is measurable (in the sense of Caratheodory) is correct. The problem is with the statement of the problem. I check the statement in the book you quote and it seems  surviving author might have missed the ***measurable*** adjective for $E$, whether that change in subsequent revisions, I don't know.

---

Here we show that if $E$ satisfies the conclussion of the problem, then **$E$ must be** measurable in the sense of Caratheodory). By Caratheodory's theorem, the outer measure $m^*$ extends $m$ to a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ that contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as well as the $m$-null sets (sets with outer measure $0$).

If $F$ is an $F_\sigma$ set and $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set, then both are Borel measurable.
So, if in addition, $F\subset E\subset G$, $m^*(F)=m^*(G)=m^*(E)<\infty$, then $m^*(G\setminus F)=0$. Indeed,  since $F$ and $G$ are Borel sets
$$\mu(G)=\mu^*(G)=m^*(F)+m^*(G\setminus F)=m(F)+m(G\setminus F)$$
Since $m^*(E)<\infty$, $m(G\setminus F)=m(G)-m(F)=0$.
This would imply the $m^*$-measurability of $E$ for
$$E=F\cup(E\setminus F),$$
$F\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathcal{M}$, and  $E\setminus F\in\mathcal{M}$ on account that  $m^*(E\setminus F)\leq m(G\setminus F)=0$.

---

As a counter example to the statement of the problem as it is written in the book, consider a the classical [Vitali](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1211067/121671) set $A$ constructed using the Axiom of choice and the equivalence  $r\sim s$ if $r-s\in\mathbb{Q}$. $A$ set is not Lebesgue measurable measurable; $E=A\cap[0,1]$ satisfies $m^*(E)=1$ and
$$\sup\{m(F):F\,\text{closed}\,,F\subset E\}=0$$